# iPhone switching on when plugged in and I really don't want that

Tags: charging

Right. Short question. I have read previous threads about how it is a feature that the iPhone switches itself on when plugged in. To me it is more of a pain. I have an iPhone because that is the only option my employer offers and if I could have the damned thing switched off and tucked away in a drawer behind a cupboard in a landfill I would. It is an overpriced rubbish piece of equipment.

Is there really no way of keeping it off when plugging it in? The bloody thing wakes me up in the middle of the night if I have forgotten to switch it off AGAIN after plugging it in.

Comment: Turn it face down, turn off bluetooth and wifi, and the ringer. Maybe get yourself some hard liquor, because it's probably moving a ton of data on your network in the dead of the night. You know, curating your privacy.

Comment: If you’re just concerned about notifications, you can schedule do not disturb to always be on during non-work hours.

Comment: I've been using iPhones for ten years or so & not once has one woken me in the middle of the night. Why not, instead of ranting about it, investigate what you're doing wrong? Also, please define "turning it off". You mean actually power down, so it has to reboot?? I'm not sure why you'd think you had to do that. It can't run its [silent] backup & maintenance schedules if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Plug it in, then turn it off. Has worked 100% of the time for me. You just have to get into the habit of doing this. Takes time and a little willpower.